# Google Play Services Library Import Makes head error eclipse

Tags: android, google-play-services

When i am importing Google play services library to my project  for ads , my project is not able to launch.
I am using parse library for push notification.

When i remove Google play services library it work fine . Why this problem could be and how to solve it ?

Comment: Please post your log errors.

Comment: there are no log errors i am getting heap error in eclipse, when adding google play services as a library project in my application

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search got me:

[How to increase Eclipse Heap #1](http://choorucode.com/2013/09/29/how-to-increase-heap-space-of-eclipse/)
[How to increase Eclipse Heap #2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)

Someone said indexing files could create JVM OutofMemory Exeptions..
Did you try that?